# My Android TV app only works on Android TV emulator (Android Studio)

Tags: android, android-tv

My Android TV app only works on Android TV Emulator (Android Studio).
When I install the application on my tv box, the application crashes

here is my Androidmanifest and my activity

Androidmanifest :

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox">

    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.software.leanback"
        android:required="true" />
    <uses-feature
        android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen"
        android:required="false" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"

        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
        tools:ignore="GoogleAppIndexingWarning">

        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.ErrorActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.VideoDetailsActivity2" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.VideoDetailsActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.SignUpActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.PlayerActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.LoginActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.ItemGenreActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.ItemCountryActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.ActivationActivity" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.SearchActivity" />
        <activity
            android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.LeanbackActivity"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme" />

        <activity
            android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.SplashScreenActivity"
            android:banner="@drawable/ic_launcher_tv"
            android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_tv"
            android:roundIcon="@drawable/ic_launcher_tv"
            android:logo="@drawable/ic_launcher_tv">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LEANBACK_LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.LoginChooserActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="fullSensor"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize" />
        <activity android:name="com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.MainActivity" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

here is my activity

activity:

````js
```
package com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.fragments;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentManager;
import androidx.leanback.app.RowsSupportFragment;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ArrayObjectAdapter;
import androidx.leanback.widget.HeaderItem;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ListRow;
import androidx.leanback.widget.ListRowPresenter;
import androidx.leanback.widget.OnItemViewClickedListener;
import androidx.leanback.widget.OnItemViewSelectedListener;
import androidx.leanback.widget.Presenter;
import androidx.leanback.widget.Row;
import androidx.leanback.widget.RowPresenter;

import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.Config;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.NetworkInst;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.utils.PreferenceUtils;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.R;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.database.DatabaseHelper;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.model.Channel;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.model.HomeContent;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.model.VideoContent;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.network.RetrofitClient;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.network.api.HomeApi;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.BackgroundHelper;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.ErrorActivity;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.LeanbackActivity;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.PlayerActivity;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.activity.VideoDetailsActivity;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.presenter.CardPresenter;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.presenter.SliderCardPresenter;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.ui.presenter.TvPresenter;
import com.tvonhd.uniplaytvbox.utils.PaidDialog;

import java.util.List;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.Callback;
import retrofit2.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;

public class HomeFragment extends RowsSupportFragment {

    private BackgroundHelper bgHelper;
    private ArrayObjectAdapter rowsAdapter;
    private CardPresenter cardPresenter;
    private View v;

    private LeanbackActivity activity;


    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        bgHelper = new BackgroundHelper(getActivity());
        activity = (LeanbackActivity) getActivity();
        activity.showLogo();


        setOnItemViewClickedListener(getDefaultItemViewClickedListener());
        setOnItemViewSelectedListener(getDefaultItemSelectedListener());


        if (new NetworkInst(activity).isNetworkAvailable()) {
            loadHomeContent();
        } else {
            Intent intent = new Intent(activity, ErrorActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            activity.finish();
        }

    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        v = super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return v;
    }


    private void loadHomeContent() {

        final SpinnerFragment mSpinnerFragment = new SpinnerFragment();
        final FragmentManager fm = getFragmentManager();
        fm.beginTransaction().add(R.id.custom_frame_layout, mSpinnerFragment).commit();

        Retrofit retrofit = RetrofitClient.getRetrofitInstance();
        HomeApi api = retrofit.create(HomeApi.class);
        Call<List<HomeContent>> call = api.getHomeContent(Config.API_KEY);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<HomeContent>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<HomeContent>> call, Response<List<HomeContent>> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    List<HomeContent> homeContents = response.body();
                    //Log.d("size:", homeContents.size()+"");

                    if (homeContents.size() > 0) {
                        loadRows(homeContents);
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(getContext(), getResources().getString(R.string.no_data_found), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }


                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getContext(), response.errorBody().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }

                // hide the spinner
                fm.beginTransaction().remove(mSpinnerFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<HomeContent>> call, Throwable t) {
                t.printStackTrace();
                Toast.makeText(getContext(), t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                // hide the spinner
                getFragmentManager().beginTransaction().remove(mSpinnerFragment).commit();
            }
        });
    }

    private void loadRows(List<HomeContent> homeContents) {

        rowsAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(new ListRowPresenter());
        cardPresenter = new CardPresenter();
        SliderCardPresenter sliderCardPresenter = new SliderCardPresenter();
        TvPresenter tvPresenter = new TvPresenter();


        int i;
        for (i = 0; i < homeContents.size(); i++) {
            ArrayObjectAdapter listRowAdapter;
            HeaderItem header;
            if (i == 0) {
                // load slider
                listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(sliderCardPresenter);
                header = new HeaderItem(i, "");
            } else if (i == 1) {
                //load tv layout
                listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(tvPresenter);
                header = new HeaderItem(i, homeContents.get(i).getTitle());
            } else {
                listRowAdapter = new ArrayObjectAdapter(cardPresenter);
                header = new HeaderItem(i, homeContents.get(i).getTitle());
            }
            //for (int j = 0; j < NUM_COLS; j++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < homeContents.get(i).getContent().size(); j++) {

                VideoContent videoContent = homeContents.get(i).getContent().get(j);

                if (homeContents.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("tv")) {
                    videoContent.setType("tv");
                } else if (homeContents.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("movie")) {
                    videoContent.setType("movie");
                } else if (homeContents.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("tvseries")) {
                    videoContent.setType("tvseries");
                } else if (homeContents.get(i).getType().equalsIgnoreCase("slider")) {
                    if (videoContent.getIsTvseries().equals("1")) {
                        videoContent.setType("tvseries");
                    } else if (videoContent.getIsTvseries().equals("0")) {
                        videoContent.setType("movie");
                    }
                }

                listRowAdapter.add(videoContent);
            }
            rowsAdapter.add(new ListRow(header, listRowAdapter));
        }

        setAdapter(rowsAdapter);

        setCustomPadding();

    }

    private void setCustomPadding() {
//        getView().setPadding(Utils.dpToPx(-24, getContext()), Utils.dpToPx(70, getContext()), 0, 0);
    }


    // click listener
    private OnItemViewClickedListener getDefaultItemViewClickedListener() {
        return new OnItemViewClickedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClicked(Presenter.ViewHolder viewHolder, Object o,
                                      RowPresenter.ViewHolder viewHolder2, Row row) {

                VideoContent videoContent = (VideoContent) o;

                String status = new DatabaseHelper(getContext()).getActiveStatusData().getStatus();

                if (videoContent.getType().equals("tv")) {
                    if (videoContent.getIsPaid().equals("1")) {
                        if (PreferenceUtils.isValid(getActivity())) {
                            if (status.equals("active")) {
                                Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class);
                                intent.putExtra("id", videoContent.getId());
                                intent.putExtra("videoType", videoContent.getStreamFrom());
                                intent.putExtra("streamUrl", videoContent.getStreamUrl());
                                startActivity(intent);
                            } else {
                                //subscription is not active
                                //new PaidDialog(getActivity()).showPaidContentAlertDialog();
                                PaidDialog dialog = new PaidDialog(getContext());
                                dialog.getWindow().setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.TRANSPARENT));
                                dialog.getWindow().setLayout(WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
                                dialog.show();
                            }
                        } else {
                            //saved data is not valid, because it was saved more than 2 hours ago
                            PreferenceUtils.updateSubscriptionStatus(getActivity());
                        }
                    } else {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), PlayerActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra("id", videoContent.getId());
                        intent.putExtra("videoType", videoContent.getStreamFrom());
                        intent.putExtra("streamUrl", videoContent.getStreamUrl());
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }

                } else {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(getActivity(), VideoDetailsActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("id", videoContent.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("type", videoContent.getType());
                    intent.putExtra("thumbImage", videoContent.getThumbnailUrl());

                    startActivity(intent);
                }


            }
        };
    }


    //listener for setting blur background each time when the item will select.
    protected OnItemViewSelectedListener getDefaultItemSelectedListener() {
        return new OnItemViewSelectedListener() {
            public void onItemSelected(Presenter.ViewHolder itemViewHolder, final Object item,
                                       RowPresenter.ViewHolder rowViewHolder, Row row) {

                if (item instanceof VideoContent) {
                    bgHelper = new BackgroundHelper(getActivity());
                    bgHelper.prepareBackgroundManager();
                    bgHelper.startBackgroundTimer(((VideoContent) item).getPosterUrl());
                } else if (item instanceof Channel) {

                    bgHelper = new BackgroundHelper(getActivity());
                    bgHelper.prepareBackgroundManager();
                    bgHelper.startBackgroundTimer(((Channel) item).getPosterUrl());

                }

            }
        };
    }

}
````

My Android TV app only works on Android TV Emulator (Android Studio). When I install the application on my TV Box, the application crashes. this error is caused by leanback?
Thanks for your help

Comment: 1. Declaring `android:required="true"` for leanback means that Android TV is the only thing the app will run on. 2. Not all TV boxes running Android are Android TV, they may just be running regular Android (using tablet layout). You should at least mention the make/model/OS version of your TV box.

Comment: Please include the stacktrace from the crash via ADB

Comment: Please add your crash logs so that we can identify the crash issue

Answer (score 0):

Make `android.software.leanback` feature required false.

```
<uses-feature
    android:name="android.software.leanback"
    android:required="false" />
```

If you set the required attribute value to true, your app will run only on devices that use the Leanback UI.